# user input `nextLine` and `nextInt` order

Tags: java, input

Below are two scripts that only differ in the order the user is asked for input. Script #1 works, whereas Script #2 doesn't work as expected.
In Script #1 I ask the `name` question first, then the `age` question.
In Script #2 I ask the `age`  question first, then the `name` question.

Script #1 (works):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initiate a new Scanner
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Name Question
        System.out.print("\nWhat is your name? ");
        String name = userInputScanner.nextLine();

        // Age Question
        System.out.print("How old are you?");
        int age = userInputScanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nHello " + name + ". You are " + age
                + " years old");
    }
}
```

Script #2 (doesn't work):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initiate a new Scanner
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Age Question
        System.out.print("How old are you?");
        int age = userInputScanner.nextInt();

        // Name Question
        System.out.print("\nWhat is your name? ");
        String name = userInputScanner.nextLine();


        System.out.println("\nHello " + name + ". You are " + age
                + " years old");
    }
}
```

in Script #2, After the user enters `age`, he/she gets the following printed to console:

```
What is your name? 
Hello . You are 28 years old
```

And then the script ends, without allowing him/her to enter a `name`

My question:
Why doesn't script #2 work?
What can I do to get script #2 to work (while maintaining order of inputs)

Comment: What do you mean by doesnt work? Any errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to consume the EOL (end of line) after reading the age:

```
    System.out.print("How old are you?");
    int age = userInputScanner.nextInt();
    userInputScanner.nextLine();


    // Name Question
    System.out.print("\nWhat is your name? ");
    String name = userInputScanner.nextLine();
```

If you do not do it, the EOL symbol will consumed at `String name = userInputScanner.nextLine();` and that's why you can't input it.

Answer (score 4):

When you read a line, it reads the entire line up to the end.

When you read a number, it just reads the number, it doesn't read the end of the line for example, unless you call `nextInt()` again in which case it will read the new line as whitespace.

In short, if you expect the input to ignore anything after the number, write

```
int age = userInputScanner.nextInt();
userInputScanner.nextLine(); // ignore the rest of the line.
```

In your case, your `nextLine()` will be reading the text after the number or empty string if you didn't enter anything.

Answer (score 2):

The `nextInt()` method will not consume the carriage return from the input stream. You need to consume it by yourself.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initiate a new Scanner
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Age Question
        System.out.print("How old are you?");
        int age = userInputScanner.nextInt();

        // consume carriage return
        userInputScanner.nextLine();

        // Name Question
        System.out.print("\nWhat is your name? ");
        String name = userInputScanner.nextLine();


        System.out.println("\nHello " + name + ". You are " + age
                + " years old");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user inputs a number (lets say 21) the input actually is: "21\n".

You need to skip the "\n" with an additional call of nextLine:

```
// Age Question
System.out.print("How old are you?");
int age = userInputScanner.nextInt();
userInputScanner.nextLine(); // skip "\n"
```